# Will c++ range-based for loop call the destructor of iterator?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, c++17, destructor

When trying to implement an iterator of a double-pointer, I found something interesting:

- The timing of the destructor being called confuses me.
- Unable to understand the memory addresses of the objects.

---

## Explanation

### `class A`

I have a class called `A`, which will allocate some memory for a sequence of integers ( `_ori_aa` ).

```cpp
class A {
public:
    // constructor and destructor
    // ...
    Iter<int> aa() const {
        Iter<int> _iter;
        _iter.set(_aa, _len);
        return _iter;
    }
private:
    const int _len;
    int * _ori_aa;  // sequence of numbers: {0, 1, 2, 3}
    int ** _aa;     // pointers to _ori_aa: {_ori_aa, _ori_aa+1, ...}
};
```

---

### `struct Iter`

And a struct called `Iter`, which can help me to iterate the double-pointer `_aa` in an `A` object.

For observation, I print the memory address of itself ( `this` ) in the constructor and destructor.

The function `meow()` also prints the memory address, but it is used for a manual call.

```
template <typename T>
struct Iter {
    Iter() { cout << '+' << this << endl; }
    ~Iter() { cout << '-' << this << endl; }
    // ...
    void meow() {
        cout << '?' << this << endl;
    }
    // ...
};
```

---

### `main()`

In the main function,

1. I create an object of `A` and then call `aa()`, which will **generate an `Iter` object** and return by value.
2. I create an object of `Iter` and call `meow()` manually to **see its address**.
3. I use **range-based for loop** to print all the numbers.
4. I print a divider to indicate the **end of the loop**.

```
int main() {
    A a;
    Iter<int> aa = a.aa();      // copy by value
    aa.meow();
    for(const int & n : aa) {
        cout << n << endl;
    }
    cout << "-------" << endl;
}
```

---

## Problem

This is the output of the program:

```
+0x7ffee567a9b0
?0x7ffee567a9b0
0
1
2
3
-0x7ffee567a988
-------
-0x7ffee567a9b0
```

**My questions are:**

1. What operations do these printed addresses correspond to?
2. I know the first address is printed when `_iter` is created in `aa()`, but when does the destructor be called? I thought `_iter` will be destroyed just after `aa()` return, while it didn't seem to do.
3. I thought the last address is printed when the object `aa` ( local variable in `main()` ) is destroyed. Since it is the same as the address of `_iter`, does it mean the memory of `_iter` had already been freed? Then why the destructor didn't be called?
4. What is the third address? Why it is different from all the addresses printed by the constructor? Why a destructor is called at the end of the for loop?

---

## Environment

- OS: macOS Catalina
- Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)
- Compilation options: `-std=c++17`

---

## Code

The following is the complete code,

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct Iter {
    Iter() { cout << '+' << this << endl; }
    ~Iter() { cout << '-' << this << endl; }

    T ** pp {nullptr};
    int len {0};
    int it {0};

    void meow() {
        cout << '?' << this << endl;
    }
    void set(T ** pi, int l) {
        pp = pi;
        len = l;
    }
    Iter & begin() {
        it = 0;
        return *this;
    }
    int end() const {
        return len;
    }

    T & operator*() {
        return *pp[it];
    }
    bool operator!=(int rhs) {
        return this->it < rhs;
    }
    Iter & operator++() {
        ++it;
        return *this;
    }
};

class A {
public:
    A() : _len(4) {
        _ori_aa = new int [_len];
        _aa = new int * [_len];
        for(int i = 0; i < _len; i++) {
            _ori_aa[i] = i;
            _aa[i] = _ori_aa + i;
        }
    }
    ~A() {
        delete [] _aa;
        delete [] _ori_aa;
    }
    Iter<int> aa() const {
        Iter<int> _iter;
        _iter.set(_aa, _len);
        return _iter;
    }
private:
    const int _len;
    int * _ori_aa;
    int ** _aa;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    Iter<int> aa = a.aa();      // copy by value
    aa.meow();
    for(const int & n : aa) {
        cout << n << endl;
    }
    cout << "-------" << endl;
}
```

**Thank you for your reading!**

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: 0x7ffee567a9b0 is obviously the address of aa.  0x7ffee567a988 must be a copy of aa (You didn't implement a copy constructor so you don't get to see it being constructed.

Comment: Add a copy constructor to `Iter` and you should see more of that is going on.

Comment: And compile with -fno-elide-consteructors to make sure you see the copy constructor working.

Comment: Look at this: https://onlinegdb.com/r18W8QYwL  The first constructor is when you create it.  The second copy is made by the for loop.  The for loop also destructs the copy.  And then at the end of main() the one you made is destructed.

Comment: Your `Iter` is neither an iterator nor a range, yet you're trying to use it as both. You should look up what the C++ model for ranges and iterators is. You're going to be in for a lot of surprises with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

A range-based for statement:

```
for (const int & n : aa) {
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Is just syntax sugar for the following (see [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)):

```
{
    auto&& __range = aa;
    auto __begin = __range.begin();
    auto __end = __range.end();
    for (; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        const int & n = *__begin;
        cout << n << endl;
    }
}
```

Which should help you understand both where your other `Iter` is being constructed and where it is being destroyed.

Note that there are exactly two `Iter` objects being constructed in this program: the one named `aa` and the one in the desugared for statement named `__begin`. The one named `_iter` inside of `aa()` is constructed in place in `aa`.